# Iterate through an object and launch its functions

Tags: javascript

I have an object that looks like this:

```
  a =
  {
    b:
    {
      f: function()
      {
        console.log("B");
      }
    }
    c:
    {
      f: function()
      {
        console.log("C");
      }
    }
  }
```

How can I iterate through the main object, so the code goes through the main entry of what it contains and then executes their `f()` function without mentioning names of each single entry? The "f" can be mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

This is one way:

```
Object.values(a).forEach((obj) => { obj.f();}) ;
```

Comment: Straight to the point of what I wanted. Thank you!